# Display recurring dates from SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm accessing a database created by another web company to retrieve event information for my current client. My client enters info for events and notes whether the date is recurring or not. I'm trying to display all the recurring dates. So far I have been able to get everything to display, regular dates as well as recurring.

The tables are laid out as follows:

- Events
- Events_Recurring

Here is part of the Events table [BIGGER PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaf9.png)

[image: events table]

This is what the Events_Recurring table looks like

[image: events recurring table]

When the client checks it as recurring, the events_recurring table creates a row with the Event ID and other information like what day of the week or month the event is recurring on.

I'm just not sure how to display multiples of that certain ID that is recurring. I have a start date, and end date I can access, as well as what day of the week it is recurring on.

So for example: If this event reoccured every thursday. and I knew it started on Jan 1st and ended Jan 31st, can I run through that and spit out 4 different events all with the date of every Thursday in January?

Here is the full code I am working with, it's a little messy while trying to figure this out. I'm checking for the recurrence towards the bottom

```
// Access external database
$events_db = new wpdb(TOP SECRET CREDENTIALS HERE);
$events_db->show_errors();

if ($events_db) :
    // Query Events Database
    $events = $events_db->get_results(
        "
        SELECT ID, RequestDateStart, RequestDateEnd, Ministry, RequestTimeStart, EventName, CoordinatorName, EventDescription, Location
        FROM gc_events
        WHERE PrivateEvent = 0
        AND Ministry = 15
        AND date(RequestDateStart)>=date(NOW())
        ORDER BY RequestDateStart
        "
    );

    // Create the event data that will be displayed
    foreach ($events as $event) :

        // Store Event ID in a variable
        $masterID = $event->ID;

        echo '<div class="col-12">';

        echo '<strong>ID:</strong> ' . $event->ID . '<br /><strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Leader:</strong> ' . $event->CoordinatorName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j',strtotime($event->RequestDateStart)) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));

        // CHECK IF RECURRING

        $recurring_events = $events_db->get_results(
            "
            SELECT gc_event_id, period, day
            FROM gc_event_recurring
            WHERE gc_event_id = '$masterID'
            "
        );

        foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event) :
        if ($recurring_event->period === 'week') {

        echo '<div class="col-12"><strong>&uarr; WEEKLY</strong><br />';

        echo $recurring_event->day;

        echo '</div>';

        }
        endforeach;

        echo '</div>';

    endforeach;
endif;
```

**The result I am getting right now (with recurring events) is**

Event: Weekly Prayer
Date: Feb 1, 2013

**The result I would like is**

Event: Weekly Prayer
Date: Feb 1, 2013

Event: Weekly Prayer
Date: Feb 8, 2013

Event: Weekly Prayer
Date: Feb 15, 2013

Event: Weekly Prayer
Date: Feb 22, 2013

---

This would be if the start date was Feb 1st and end date was Feb 28th.

Comment: your question is confuding can you please show the code and yes please try to define you question in a good way dnt panic just be calm and write

Comment: Trying not to panic :) added a bit more info, as well as the code I'm working with

Comment: so, recurring event is displayed multiple times?

Comment: `($recurring_event->period === 'week')` do not use `===` use `==`

Comment: @SparKot only once. I would like to essentially display the same data for each day that the event recurs on throughout the time span that is set.

Comment: do you need to display all the info about an event and also event's recurring info? you can get all info in single query select * events from events left join events_recurring on events.id = events_recurring.gc_event_id WHERE Date between startDate and endDate. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Recurring event has single entry in table, but when events for a month are pulled a weekly recurring-event pops only once. That's the problem.

Comment: so you want to display id:2203 3 time with diffrent date on that particular monthn like 6th feb,13 feb and 20 feb

Comment: what is the type of column period in events_recurring? can you add table structure and some test data?

Comment: @SparKot I'm sorry I should have been more clear, there are months as well. These are only being shown once as well.

Comment: please post table structure and temp data; also the sample result you would like to obtain

Comment: @rohitarora yes! :) AndaLancu I posted an image of the table above

Comment: what's the purpose of `events` table? Is if for events already occurred or scheduled? Add Schema of `events` table as well please.

Comment: Just one more stuf as i am not clear what type of out put you want please share the out put you want ill do it :

Comment: @AndaIancu I posted it towards the end as well as the sample table data

Comment: @rohitarora I posted the output I am looking to get at the bottom :) Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @ftntravis Why can't you have the `events` table populated with the recurring-events? I mean whenever they're added.

Comment: `Events_Recurring` table entries don't make sense! is that all? Where are the dates between which they need to occur? `Validity Period`?

Comment: @SparKot I know! :( I wish I knew what they were trying to do. If you look in the events table it has a request start and end date.

Comment: Wow, so many comments. One more: is it (or should it be) possible to cancel or move a single occurrence of an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach ($events as $event) :

                // Store Event ID in a variable
                $masterID = $event->ID;

                echo '<div class="col-12">';

                echo '<strong>ID:</strong> ' . $event->ID . '<br /><strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Leader:</strong> ' . $event->CoordinatorName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j',strtotime($event->RequestDateStart)) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));

                // CHECK IF RECURRING

                $recurring_events = $events_db->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT gc_event_id, period, day
                    FROM gc_event_recurring
                    WHERE gc_event_id = '$masterID'
                    "
                );

                foreach ($recurring_events as $recurring_event) :
                if ($recurring_event->period == 'week') {
                $StartDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateStart);
                $EndDate = strtotime($event->RequestDateEnd);
$TotalDays = round(($EndDate-$StartDate)/(60*60*24*7));
                for($i = 0 ;$i<($TotalDays-1);$i++)
                {
                $StartDate += (60*60*24*7);
                echo '<div class="col-12">';

                echo '<strong>ID:</strong> ' . $event->ID . '<br /><strong>Event Name:</strong> ' . $event->EventName . '<br /><strong>Leader:</strong> ' . $event->CoordinatorName . '<br /><strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('l, F j',$StartDate) . '<br /><strong>Start Time:</strong> ' . date('g:i a',strtotime($event->RequestTimeStart));


                }


                }
                endforeach;

                echo '</div>';

            endforeach;
```

try this and tell me if it works

Comment: `$recurring_event->day` is `day of the week` I believe.

Comment: but in the table its a count i think.see in the question.he can use that thing as count what ever it is

Comment: ahh almost! I thought it was working, but in checking them, some are going past the date they are supposed to end. The client enters in a start date and end date which I can use. I'm guessing these could fix the problem of going past?

Comment: whats the problem you facing and can you show me the out put you getting now?

Comment: you can see here: http://beta.revival.tv/test/ events that are supposed to end are still being populated with more dates.

Comment: Sorry i was adding the timestamp two side now try again sorry for my mistake

Comment: @rohitarora no worries. But it is still doing the same thing :/ For instance the first one populated goes from Feb 2nd to March 9th when it should go from Feb 2nd to Feb 23rd. That's why I'm wondering if we can implement that End Date data somehow into what you have to tell it to not go past it.

Comment: http://beta.revival.tv/test/ its looking fine i think it going in right direction and adding the day you want..is it missing any thing

Comment: @ftntravis Are all the events listed on that page sorted by date? Otherwise, it's confusing for the readers!

Comment: it should show inside the month?i mean you have many condition which you dint told completly

Comment: @rohitarora I think it's almost there. But, if you look at the test site the very first event, the quilting class, should end on Feb 23rd, instead it is ending on March 9th. Can we use the START and END dates to keep it within those dates?

Comment: that is why i am asking.can you please tell me the days in db?for first event from Events_Recurring table

Comment: @SparKot Yes they are sorted by date, it will be in a lot nicer format once I get the right data to display :)

Comment: @rohitarora yes! :) sorry. The START date is $event->RequestDateStart the END date is $event->RequestDateEnd does that help?

Comment: yes that can help but the days also can help.can you please tell me the day in Events_Recurring of 2345 id.

Comment: @rohitarora sorry had to get some sleep. The day can be pulled from $recurring_event->day which will return a number. For example a 3 if it is recurring every wednesday.

Comment: can you tell me for id 2345 if its more than 4 than we have to use last date also cz that will exceed month.if its 4 than might be something wrong with the loop and i will review it.

Comment: @rohitarora yes it is displaying 5 right now. It should only show 4 though. So I'm guessing we need to use the last date

Comment: @rohitarora For example the event with ID of 2401 is only showing 3 right now when it should show many more. It is set up from Feb to Dec to recur so there should be a lot more than 3 showing.

Comment: i forgot to tell you that i have edited the answer yesterday.

Comment: @rohitarora can't thank you enough for your help on this. I appreciate it!

Comment: @rohitarora everything is working as expected. I have run into the problem of sorting it now? I have tried putting it in an array with no luck. The array gets a bunch of empty values because of the IF statement I think. I have opened another question here: http://bit.ly/XUcGUe if you want to take a shot at it :)

Answer (score 12):

A word of advice.

Although designing a database to store the 'description' of the repetition pattern is a very clean approach from a design point-of-view, you may get a lot of problems down the way.

I've done a project with a similar approach a while ago (I will look up the database design and add that to my answer) and, although I was able to reproduce the exact date/times of the recurring events, you will run into problems in the following situations; most originate from this:

**the recurring events *describe* the repetition pattern, so the actual (individual) events are no *physical* records in your database**

1. If the customer decides to add a new event, how will you check if it overlaps with any existing event? You'll have to calculate all 'events', based on the repetition pattern.
2. If the customer decides that the scheduled time for an event needs to be changed, how will you have this change apply to all *future* events and not for events that are in the past (you'll have to duplicate the original event, modify its end-date, and set the duplicated event with a new start-date)
3. If the customer decides he wants to *remove* a single day from the repetition pattern (e.g. a single event has ben canceled), you will also have to split the original event into *two* separate repetitions, *or* have a 'canceled/blocked' dates/times table
4. If people need to 'book' for specific events, you won't be able to attach them to a 'real' event-record, because the individual events because they are not physically present in the database. e.g. to check if a single event can be re-scheduled or canceled, you'll need to do this from code as the database cannot make use of foreign-key constraints to automatically update related reservations
5. Regarding performance; because individual events are not physically stored, they will have to be calculated *every time* you want to show them. Consider having 1000 recurring events in the database and try to show a 'calendar' of week 23 two years from now. You'll have to analyze *all* recurring-events patterns and calculate *all* events that they produce!

All depends of course on the actual usage of your system, but I wanted to warn you for problems we've run into.

Here's the schema for the 'schedules' table (contains recurring events pattern);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedules` (
  `id`              int(11)     NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_start`      date        NOT NULL,
  `time_start`      time        NOT NULL,
  `time_end`        time        NOT NULL,
  `recur_until`     date        default NULL COMMENT 'end date when recurrence stops',
  `recur_freq`      varchar(30) default NULL COMMENT 'null, "secondly", "minutely", "hourly", "daily", "weekly", "monthly", "yearly"',
  `recur_interval`  smallint(5) unsigned default NULL COMMENT 'e.g. 1 for each day/week, 2 for every other day/week',
  `recur_byday`     smallint(5) unsigned default NULL COMMENT 'BITWISE; monday = 1, sunday = 64',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

### How to circumvent the problems described

Fully describing a solution to these problems won't probably be suitable here, but here's some things to consider;

Storing a recurring event as described on itself is *not* bad practice. It perfectly describes when, and how often, an event should take place. However, the lack of physical records for the actual events is what causes the problem.

1. When *creating* or *modifying* a recurring event, calculate all resulting events and store them as physical records. These records can be queried, 'reservations' can be attached to them and you'll be able to make use of database features, like foreign-key-constraints to handle them properly.
2. When storing the individual events as described in 1., make sure you're keeping a reference to the 'schedule' that they belong to. If (for example) the customer wants to change the time of a recurring event, you'll be able to update all related (individual) events.
3. Keep in mind that in situation 2, you'll probably only want to update *future* events, so the 'recurring event' will still need to be 'split' in two to achieve that. In which case 'future' events need to be attached to the new 'recurring event', old events stay attached to the existing 'recurring event'

**invest time in your database/software design**, properly investigate if the design will 'work' for the thing you're trying to achieve. Test it, try things and if they don't work, don't hesitate to 'throw it away', often it's easier to start from scratch than try to 'fix' things. A proper design will take time and may take several 'redesigns' to get it right, but it **will** save you time and money in the end.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Wow, thank you for that information! I actually just started messing around with databases this week. I didn't build the current database I am working with, just trying to pull information from it. You did make some solid points though that I will keep in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @ftntravis You're welcome. I'll add some additional information to my post that may circumvent the problems described

Comment: I love it. Thanks! This is a great response, coming from a graphic design background I can definitely see the art of building a nice, readable database.